# olの番号の縦位置が下になってしまう。上揃えにしたい。

Tags: html, css

キャプチャのようにliの番号が下揃えになってしまいます。
＊キャプチャの赤い位置にしたい。
（safariで下になります。chromeでは上になっています）

次のようにしても上になりません。

```
ol li {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

どうすれば良いでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ol li img { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！imgの`float:left`の解除と合わせるとできました！